# How can i use NSSavePanel to select a directory?

Tags: cocoa, macos, nssavepanel

I need the user select an existing or a new directory where my app can save a few files.

Can i do this with NSSavePanel or is there another directory selector class?

Comment: I also need this because given the new sandboxing rules, NSOpenPanel will return a folder in the app's container

Answer (score 29):

[NSSavePanel](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSSavePanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't give the ability to choose folders but [NSOpenPanel](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (a subclass of NSSavePanel) does. You set YES for -setCanChooseDirectories: and -setCanCreateDirectories:, set a prompt that makes sense with -setPrompt:.

Comment: Will Apple approve usage of open panel instead of save ?
(I think I saw an app that opened and NSOpenPanel on save, but I am not sure it was app I downloaded from app store