# Disable NSSavePanel "Save As:" text input field

Tags: objective-c, macos, nssavepanel

Stuck at this for some time now.

Does anyone know how to disable text input field on a NSSavePanel? This is how I am using it:

```
NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result)
{
...
}
```

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a very strange thing to want to do. The entire point of the "Save As" dialogue is to allow the user to specify another name for the document. If you just want to save it under a different name programmatically, don't present the dialogue.

Comment: I want to take where user wants to save the file but doesn't want to allow name change as this is the backup file and changing name would invalidate it.

Comment: I would say don't present a save panel then; use an Open panel to choose just a directory. See, e.g., [How can I use NSSavePanel to select a directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3396081)

Comment: That makes sense. I am gonna try it now. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing! Please come back when you've resolved your issue and either post an answer describing your solution, or flag for a moderator to mark this as a duplicate of the question I've linked.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. I have also flagged the question to moderator.